# Video output garbled with blue squares on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: display, 19.04

[image]

[image]

It's not a hardware problem as I have tried with different monitors and both HDMI and VGA cable and getting same problem.

System Config:

- Intel ® Core™ i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz × 16
- Intel ® HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
- GNOME 3.32.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rainy season in India and I think the RAM got some moisture. Took out the RAM and cleaned it with an eraser and put it back again. Everything works fine now!